# Change Button style, text and onClick event after successful in-app billing transaction

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-button

How do I change the text, style and onClick behavior of a Button in Android app after the BillingResponse is received as *RESULT_OK* from the server?

This will let the user know that he has purchased the app previously!

Please help me out!

Comment: You must have some type of callback when the transaction is done, right? So in this callback you should call on the UI thread (If the callback is not called there) and do whatever you need..

Comment: Ok, I call the UI thread. And what happens after that? Should I define another button with different style and onClick listener?

Comment: If you want to change the onClick behavior, then yes. And you don't need to define another button, just change the existing one's properties.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that:
When you get the RESULT_OK callback save with [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

```
sp.edit().putBoolean("purchased", true).commit();
```

And in the onCreate method of your Activity call

```
boolean purchased = sp.getBoolean("purchased", false);
```

Depending on the state of the purchased boolean you apply the style, onclick, ..